# Minix: Kernel Panic when booting from the Live CD

Tags: virtualbox, minix

I followed the instructions in the Minix wiki on [how to set up Minix in VirtualBox](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/UsersGuide/RunningMinixOnVirtualBox), but right after hitting enter on the boot screen, I get a kernel panic:

```
*** kernel messages:
ested 0
...
kernel panic: cause_sig: sig manager 2 gets lethal signal 11 for itself
...
```

I'm using VirtualBox 4.1.2 on Ubuntu 11.10. Am I doing anything wrong? How do I convince Minix to boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your hardware supports virtualization, make sure it's activated in the BIOS (some computers have the feature but ship with it disabled). Then make sure that “Enable VT-x/AMD-V” is checked in the “System → Acceleration” tab of the VM settings.

If that's not a solution for you, from VirtualBox 4.0, instead of booting Minix by hitting the Start button in VirtualBox, use this command to start the VM:

```
VBoxSDL --startvm "Minix 3" --norawr0 --norawr3
```

(where "Minix 3" is the name of the virtual machine)

The option [`--norawr0`](https://www.virtualbox.org/browser/trunk/src/VBox/Frontends/VBoxSDL/VBoxSDL.cpp#L615), possibly combined with `--norawr3`, can help with other guest operating systems such as [OpenBSD](http://jreypo.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/openbsd-and-virtualbox/), [NetBSD](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.netbsd.general/29070), [QNX](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/685)…